# HTML form that searches text (php?)

Tags: php, html, forms, search

I have a file with usernames and ip addresses (about 10MB). I want to be able to have people come to my website and enter an ip address or username and it search the database and return matches.

Case 1: User enters "Billy" in `<form>`. Output is IP address and all users who have used this IP address
Case 2: User enters ip address in `<form>`. Output is all usernames which have used this ip address.

Unfortunately I'm a true noob here, I've looked up w3schools, but haven't really found what I wanted or even how I should do this.

Probably I'll have an HTML `<form>` where user enters either IP or username and radio buttons where user specifies if what they just entered was an IP or name. After this I'm stumped, in the `<form>` should I have an `action="blah.php"` or can I create a local variable to take in this value?

EDIT:
I would like to do this all in one html file by injecting  right into the html. Probably using `$desc=$_POST['ipaddress'];` or similar? What kind of action="" should I use in the form tags?

Comment: mario's answer is great, but i would recommend using a mysql database for a storage mechanism on this and not a text file.

Comment: I have no choice in the matter, a server just spits out the data in a text file. That is the purpose of this whole thing; trying to make meaning of this mess. @Jordan

Comment: do you access to the server? modify the server's script to write to the db and not the file, if possible.

Comment: It is not possible since there is much other data in the file that the server reads. It would need major reworking of the server itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just make a single search field:

```
<form action="search.php">
<input name="q">
```

Then in the search.php script just receive the string:

```
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
```

And run through the text file:

```
$f = fopen("10MB.txt", "r");
while (($line = fgets($f)) !== FALSE) {
   if (strstr($line, $q)) {
       print "<li>found: $line"; 
   }   // outputs name+ip if either one is found in the line
}
```

This assumes that the text file contains one IP and username per line. You can fine-tune the output of course. Split it up if you want. But for searching itself its irrelevant if the form sends an ip address or a username to search for. It would match either in the text file.

Comment: Ah, brilliant :)! Anyhow I would like the HTML and PHP to be both in the same file, for example just inserting PHP in the html file with <?php ?> what should the `<form action="">` look like? Just the same link of the file itself?

Comment: The action= attribute can point to the current file then. To have it contain both the html/form and the processing logic, just use something like `if (isset($_POST["button"])) {` to enclose the above search logic, or `} else {` print the regular HTML page part.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it out as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 0):

How are you storing the usernames and ip addresses? if you are using a sql database like mysql then you can use it's search functions or a more dedicated search tool like lucene or sphinx.

Here are some references that you can follow.

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_select.asp

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html

Comment: the usernames and ip addresses are jumbled in a text file because a server just spits them out.